# Integrate requirejs text plugin into requirejs core

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requirejs with different libraries like backbone and jquery.
My plan is to use grunt to concat all my libs into one file and load it once in my index.html file, because since all the libs are needed anyway, i want to save some code. So instead of loading jquery and backbone every time i code a new backbone view or model, i simply use Backbone and jquery as it is loaded in the global scope. The only stuff i load are my views, models and collections.

But the text plugin gives me some headache. It requires to be separated from my concatenated lib files. Because every time i load a HTML file with "text!blabla.html" it first trys to load the plugin text.js before it loads the HTML file. So i cant concat the text plugin with requirejs along with all the other libs so its preloaded on page load.

Is there any possibility to integrate the text plugin into requirejs so it is "known" in the core by default. Otherwise i have one lib file with all my libraries in and text.js, because requirejs wants to asynchronously load it on demand and not get it preloaded along with requirejs itself.

Could anyone help get this solved. Actually this is not really optimized, since i am now forced to have 2 GET requests to get my libraries loaded instead of one.

Comment: [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) has solved these problems, it works with Grunt and is the standard tool for concatenating/minifying projects using require.js.

Answer (score 0):

Nikos is correct in his comment that you'd want to use `r.js` for this. In projects where all the files loaded with `text!` are known at the time of optimization, you can have `r.js` incorporate the files loaded with `text!` into the optimized bundle(s), and replace the `text!` plugin itself with a stub.

Comment: i did this, this is simply concatenating both into one, but this is NOT working. text.js is wrapped within a define call, so it needs to be loaded with require, but i want to integrate it into require js so. concat doesnt work.

Comment: I momentarily forgot that RequireJS would complain about an anonymous define. If you don't use RequireJS, it is a bit more complex than `cat` because you have to change the `define` call so that the first parameter is the name of the defined module. This is not hard to do but it is more complex than `cat`. And if you are going to do this, you might as well just use `r.js`, which will do it automatically. The first part of my answer is still correct.